# How to resolve the `at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)` and server selection error

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I have been trying to connect database locally to mongodb using nodejs but there are some errors i'm facing some errors while doing that.

In my main folder there is only one connection file named as `db.js` and other files are `package.json` and `node_modules`. This is error I got after running the `node db.js` at particular location I have installed mongoose also using `npm` command.

[image: This is error I got after running the node db.js at particular location I have installed mongoose also using npm command]

and after using the command `node --trace-deprecation` I got the following error log.

[image: after using the command node --trace-deprecation I got the following error log]

Here's the code of `db.js`:-

```js
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017').then(()=>{
    console.log(`conncn established!!\n`);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('no connection',err);
})

// module.exports=mongoose;
// "mongodb://localhost:27017/Blogs_db -->it is the connection string for Blogs_db tried to but this //string also but it is not working
```

I have checked whether my server is running or not and tried to make the new folder and to follow the process again but it still shows the connection error

Comment: Looks like `localhost` is mapped to the IPv6 address `::1` on your system.  You can either enable IPv6 on the MongoDB server, or try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Go the answer and it is simple just to replace the local host in the connection string with 0.0.0.0 and it worked[Heres the output after replacing the localhost in above code with 0.0.0.0]

Comment: I'm not sure `0.0.0.0` will work for all operating systems / network stacks.  `127.0.0.1` is generally a better option.